# Finding all products with same keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables:

```
products(product_id, product_description)
keywords(keyword_id, keyword_name)
product_keyword(FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id), FOREIGN KEY (keyword_id)  REFERENCES keywords(keyword_id))
```

If I want to return all products with the same keywords as a given product, how would I do this?

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * from products
WHERE product_keyword having product_keyword.product_id = 1 /* don't know how to make this a general statement, but let's assume that I'm looking for all products with the same keywords as product number 1
```

Can't figure it out.

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you are using.

Comment: can you please check the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to concatenate the keywords together and use that string for joining:

```
select p.product_id, p.keyword_ids
from (select product_id, group_concat(keyword_id order by keyword_id) as keyword_ids
      from product_keywords
      group by product_id
     ) p join
     (select group_concat(keyword_id order by keyword_id) as keyword_ids
      from product_keywords
      where product_id = 1
     ) p1
     on p.keyword_ids = p1.keyword_ids;
```

Another method is more cumbersome but uses more traditional SQL.  Do a self-join on keywords and a lot of counting:

```
select p.product_id
from key_words p left join
     key_words p1
     on p1.key_word = p.key_word nd
        p1.product_id = 1
group by p.product_id
having count(*) = count(p1.keyword) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from key_words pp1 where pp1.product_id = 1);
```

The `left join` keeps all keywords for each product.  The `having` then does two things:

- The `count(*)` = `count(p1.keyword)` returns only rows where all keywords match.
- The `count(*) = <subquery>` ensures that the number of keywords is the number for the first product.

Both of these formulations assume no duplicates in `product_keyword`s, which seems like a reasonable assumption.  Judicious use of `distinct` works if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

you should try the join between the all three tables , query is given below for an example .

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN product_keyword AS pk ON p.product_id = pk.product_id
INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
WHERE k.keyword_id = p.keyword_id
```

You can even set the kewword_id as in given below query.

```
 SELECT p.product_id
   ,p.product_description
   ,K.keyword_id
   ,k.keyword_name
 FROM Products AS p
 INNER JOIN product_keyword AS pk ON p.product_id = pk.product_id
 INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
 WHERE k.keyword_id = 1
```

Comment: I get an error (id 1064), when running this. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.product_description,
    k.keyword_id,
    k.keyword_name
FROM
    products p
INNER JOIN product_keyword pk ON pk.product_id = p.product_id 
INNER JOIN keywords k on k.keyword_id = pk.keyword_id
WHERE pk.keyword_id = 1
```

Comment: I get an error message (code 1064) in SELECT p.product_id :(

Comment: If I test this mesefl, I am getting `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.products' doesn't exist`. you did not provide enough details on how your tables are created, I mean output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE products` (and same for other tables)

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select product_id, group_concat(keyword_id order by keyword_id) keywords
from product_keyword
group by product_id
```

returns all the `keyword_id`s for each product as a comma separated list.
In MySql 8.0+ you can wrap it inside a CTE and compare the list returned for `product_id = 1` to the other lists:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select product_id, group_concat(keyword_id order by keyword_id) keywords
    from product_keyword
    group by product_id
  ),
  cte1 as (select * from cte where product_id = 1)
select p.* 
from products p inner join cte c 
on c.product_id = p.product_id
where c.keywords = (select keywords from cte1)
```

This will return all the products with the same keywords as `product_id = 1` including that also. If you don't want it in the results add to the `WHERE` clause:

```
and product_id <> (select product_id from cte1)
```